# CheckBox Using method that is inside another method

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i want to use the method checkbutton_value1 in another method AGM.

```
def AGM():
   def A1():
      print "A1"
   def A2():
      print "A2"
   def checkbutton_value1():
      x=var1.get()
```

I tried using checkbutton_value1 for checkbutton command but it won't work.

```
master = Tk() # Open up GUI connection
master.title('Program Application')
var1=IntVar()
checkbox_1 = Checkbutton(master, text='Interpolate Graph', variable=var1,command=checkbutton_value1)
checkbox_1.pack()
master.mainloop() # Continue loop till user close tab
```

Error message

```
NameError: name 'checkbutton_value1' is not defined
```

Comment: Where is `var1` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because you've defined `checkbutton_value1` inside AGM's namespace.

What you *need* to do is this:

```
def checkbutton_value1():
    x = var1.get()


master = Tk()  # Open up GUI connection
master.title('Program Application')
var1 = IntVar()
checkbox_1 = Checkbutton(master, text='Interpolate Graph',
                         variable=var1, command=checkbutton_value1)
checkbox_1.pack()
master.mainloop() # Continue loop till user close tab
```

Now, this will work. However, in suck cases, its just better to use a lambda:

```
checkbox_1 = Checkbutton(master, text='Interpolate Graph',
                         variable=var1, command=lambda: var1.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a larger snippet? That is probably failing because checkbutton_value1 is being defined in a scope where the line referencing it doesn't have access.

For example, this doesn't produce that error:

```
class test:

    def foo():
        pass


print(test.foo())
```